# Using db2 load for importing multiple csv into a table

Tags: csv, db2

Is it possible to use the db2 load command to point to a folder and upload all the *.csv files that exist in the folder?

I have around 17,000 csv files that I am trying to upload to an empty db2 table. Currently, I am using the TOAD software import wizard but it is very slow and I will have to do this a few other times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the basic DB2 LUW product. But add-on products may offer such automation.  Loading millions of CSV files is trivial to script however, depending on your skill level, either on Widows or Unix where the csv files live.

If the CSV files are destined for different tables you can parallelize the load actions if you have many cores at your disposal.

For more specific advice, edit your question to give details of the operating-system, and DB2-version, and what scripting tools or ETL applications are available to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just wanted to know if it can be down with the basic DB2 LUW product.